# Failed to restart fail2ban.service: Unit firehol.service not found

Tags: fail2ban

When you come accorss this error after uninstalling Firehol. Check that you don't have this block:

```
[Unit]
# Starting fail2ban will automatically start firehol before it.
# Stopping firehol will automatically stop fail2ban before it.
BindsTo=firehol.service
After=firehol.service
```

in `/etc/systemd/system/fail2ban.service.d/override.conf` or `systemctl edit fail2ban`

If you have it, delete it and start/ restart fail2ban service. Sometimes, we need to reverse what we have done when we followed the [documentation](https://github.com/firehol/firehol/wiki/fail2ban).

Answer (score 0):

Delete the block as highlighted above and run:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

You can run `fail2ban-client status` to confirm fail2ban status